# daisy chain function calls (method 1 calls method 2, method 2 calls method 3)

Tags: objective-c

I have a function that calls another function. i want the second function to call a third function. they all then return to the first function and finish the code;

```
-(void) select
{
  //do code
  [self drawMap];
}

-(void) drawMap
{
  //do code
  [self performSelector:@selector(showActionSheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}

-(void) showActionSheet
{
  //do code
}
```

But the showActionSheet function is not being called, its not firing.

EDIT: but if i change

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showActionSheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

to

```
[self showActionSheet];
```

it works fine. but i want to delay the showing of an action sheet a few seconds so the user can see the changes to the map.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an id parameter to your showActionSheet method in order for the`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` method to work correctly.

Try changing the signature of your method to:

```
-(void) showActionSheet:(id) obj { ... }
```

And as @[MByD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464988/mbyd) added, you need to add a colon to your selector:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showActionSheet:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. made the change to the function in both .h and .m file (added a id parameter) and changed the function call to add the ":". still doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a thread that does not have a **NSRunLopp**, because it is the **NSRunLoop** that not only responsible for handling inputs but it is also responsible for performing timed actions.

Also is it possible that you **NSRunLoop** is not give a chance to wait for input and fire timed events, if you have some code that is running for a long time before returning back to your **NSRunLoop** then your **NSRunLoop** will not get a change to do anything until then.

Another possibility is if you have set up you **NSRunLoop** in an odd way you may have to use

```
- [NSObject performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
                 withObject:(id)anArgument
                 afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                    inModes:(NSArray *)modes];
```

instead and try a different mode other than row default one (*NSDefaultRunLoopMode*).